# General algorithm for generating a description of the language it is written in

Tags: algorithms, programming-languages

Does there exist a general algorithm which can output a finite and complete description of the (programming) language in which it is written, if it is given the permission to execute programs in that language?

The description should be sufficient to associate a correct output for any given program in that language.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Is it whether there can be an algorithm that outputs a compiler?

Comment: Perhaps the OP is after a [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))?

Comment: I think the OP asks for an algorithm to 'reverse engineer' a compiler (or interpreter), given only access to the compiler as a black box. This sounds rather uncomputable to me.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, I am asking whether there is a general algorithm which outputs a compiler of that language given certain permissions. Is it possible to prove/disprove?

Comment: @Discretelizard That's correct.

Comment: @Bright I still don't understand your question. What does it mean for an algorithm to be "given permissions"? Algorithms aren't written in programming languages; implementations are.

Comment: In which way should this "general" algorithm be general? It's trivial to write a program that outputs the compiler of a PL in that same PL.

Comment: `cat /bin/sh` is a program trivially printing its intepreter. In any language, one can use `print "..."` where `print` is the printing syntax, and `...` is the compiler definition. This was pointed out by @Raphael. I can't understand the question.

Comment: @Raphael I meant it exactly like Discrete lizard understood it. I am sorry it's unclear to you, I cannot be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you ask for cannot exist. To show this, consider 'programming languages' where every program $P$ is a single integer (we can interpret most programs as a number, but here we will explicitly use the number). Now, consider the following class of 'compilers': $C_k$, such that the compiled program is $C_k(P):= \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $P\geq k$}\\ 0&\text{if $P<k$}\end{cases}$.

Now, suppose our compiler-reverse engineering program has come to the conclusion that some black box compiler $C$ behaves as $C_{k^*}$ for a finite number of programs, the largest one being $P'$. But then $C_{k^*}$ is indistinguishable from $C_k$ for all $k>k^*$, so our procedure cannot determine the behaviour of $C$ with only a finite number of inputs.

So, as any algorithm must test an infinite amount of inputs, there is no algorithm that correctly decides even these simple languages.